# How do I convert a Firestore date/Timestamp to a JS Date()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to convert the below date to a javascript Date() object. When I get it back from the server, it is a Timestamp object,

**Screenshot from Firebase Firestore console:**

[image]

When I try the following on a list of objects returned from firestore:

```
  list.forEach(a => {
    var d = a.record.dateCreated;
    console.log(d, new Date(d), Date(d))
  })
```

**I get this output:**
[image]

Clearly the Timestamps are all different, and are not all the same date of Sept 09, 2018 (which happens to be today). I'm also not sure why `new Date(Timestamp)` results in an `invalid date`. I'm a bit of a JS newbie, am I doing something wrong with the dates or timestamps?

Answer (score 263, accepted):

The constructor for a JavaScript's `Date` doesn't know anything about Firestore's [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) objects — it doesn't know what to do with them.

If you want to convert a `Timestamp` to a `Date`, use the [`toDate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) method on the `Timestamp`.

Comment: @blueether or somebody else could post a working exemple ? Because I only get an error `...toDate() is not a function`.

Comment: toDate() is not a function

Comment: toDate is not a function, and when i m trying to convert time, it give some weird 3 months or 4 months old date

Comment: @ChiragJoshi Without the ability to see and run your code, there's not much we can say.  I suggest posting a new question with your specific details.

Comment: @DougStevenson toDate() is giving error, i m using this var time=data.val().time; and gives me the date - 11-09-2020 11:43+0530 and where as my database date  - 28-01-2021 03:48:07+0530

Comment: @ChiragJoshi  You should post a new question that fully explains what you're doing and what doesn't work the way you expect.  A comment on an answer is not a good place for this.

Comment: Ypu should change type to any to avoid "is not a function" error.

Comment: @Nitneq see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68248054/3073272

Comment: toDate is nested under the writeTime object: `yourTimestamp.writeTime.toDate()`

Comment: Just trying to understand. Why should the OP post a new question instead of updating his current question?

Comment: For anyone struggling with this, ensure you're actually dealing with the Timestamp object, not a JSON interpretation.  If it's not a Timestamp object, you'll hit `toDate() is not a function` for obvious reasons.

Comment: Anyone who is getting the `toDate() is not a function` error and using the JavaScript SDK: For me I could simply convert the timestamp directly into a date using `new Date(timestamp)`.

Comment: for anyone who is having `toDate() is not a function` error might be because you are using it on a JSON object. You can simply use the timestamp object received from firebase, or If you are not able to use it directly then To convert it back to timestamp object you can do this:

`const timestamp = new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(jsonTimestamp.seconds, jsonTimestamp.nanoseconds)`
now doing `timestamp.toDate()` will work

Comment: @RahulKumar I like your answer . But what if I have Timestamp data and non timestamp data ? how to handle this situation ? Because I have original timestamp data. Then I will convert it to JSON and I will import again as JSON . so I have JSON object TimeStamp. How to handle these two things . I can't check the data type because they are same data type but different constructor class vs object .

Comment: wow @RahulKumar , I am very happy right now , Now firestore can understand my imported JSON timestamp . Will get error when seconds and nanosecods order change. here is my working code 
`timeStamp: new Timestamp(d.timeStamp?.seconds!, d.timeStamp?.nanoseconds!),` 

when code is nanseconds,seconds ( it will get time range error)

Answer (score 85):

You can use `toDate()` function along with `toDateString()` to display the date part alone.

```
const date = dateCreated.toDate().toDateString()
//Example: Friday Nov 27 2017
```

Suppose you want only the time part then use the `toLocaleTimeString()`

```
const time = dateCreated.toDate().toLocaleTimeString('en-US')
//Example: 01:10:18 AM, the locale part 'en-US' is optional
```

Comment: This answer was what I was looking for.  One additional tip for anyone wanting to convert the respective time (central time, in my case) to Eastern/New York time, you can do something like this:`const time = dateCreated.toDate().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' })`

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer.

Comment: If this is the your looking for please mark it as answer

Answer (score 39):

You can use [`Timestamp.fromDate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#constructor) and [`.toDate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) for converting back and forth.

```js
// Date to Timestamp
const t = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());

// Timestamp to Date
const d = t.toDate();
```

Comment: Love you bro!
Thanks a lotttt!!!!

Answer (score 31):

apart from other answers you can do it like this as well

```js
    //date from firebase is represented as
    let time = {
      seconds: 1613748319,
      nanoseconds: 47688698687,
    }
    
    const fireBaseTime = new Date(
      time.seconds * 1000 + time.nanoseconds / 1000000,
    );
    const date = fireBaseTime.toDateString();
    const atTime = fireBaseTime.toLocaleTimeString();


    console.log(date, atTime);
```

Answer (score 29):

How to convert Unix timestamp to JavaScript Date object.

```
var myDate = a.record.dateCreated;
new Date(myDate._seconds * 1000); // access the '_seconds' attribute within the timestamp object
```

Answer (score 24):

Please use `toDate()` method and then convert it into the format using angular pipe like this -

```
   {{ row.orderDate.toDate() | date: 'dd MMM hh:mm' }}
```

Comment: This did not work for me, it fails. Angular? Who said is using Angular first of all?!

Answer (score 13):

At last, I could get what I need. This returns date as `08/04/2020`

```
new Date(firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds*1000).toLocaleDateString()
```

Answer (score 12):

```js
const timeStampDate = record.createdAt;
const dateInMillis  = timeStampDate._seconds * 1000

var date = new Date(dateInMillis).toDateString() + ' at ' + new Date(dateInMillis).toLocaleTimeString()
```

OutPut Example: `Sat 11 Jul 2020 at 21:21:10`

Answer (score 10):

This might help:

```
new Date(firebaseDate._seconds * 1000).toUTCString()
```

Answer (score 9):

A simple way is to convert firestore timestamp to epoch timestamp is by using `toMillis()` method on firestore timestamp.

For example:
You have a firestore timestamp 
`created_on : Timestamp { _seconds: 1622885490, _nanoseconds: 374000000 }`

```
let epochTimestamp = created_on.toMillis()
//epochTimestamp = 1621081015081
//Now this timestamp can be used as usual javascript timestamp which is easy to manipulate.
let date = new Date(epochTimestamp) //date = Sat May 15 2021 17:46:55 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 6):

The timestamp object you get from firestore has a `toDate()` method you can use.

```js
list.forEach(a => {
  var d = a.record.dateCreated;
  console.log(d.toDate())
})
```

Here's a quote from firebase docs about the `toDate()` method

> Convert a Timestamp to a JavaScript Date object. This conversion
> causes a loss of precision since Date objects only support millisecond
> precision.
>
> Returns Date JavaScript Date object representing the same point in
> time as this Timestamp, with millisecond precision.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate

Answer (score 4):

Lots of answer here, but as a rookie I found most of them confusing.

So for rookies like me, here is a simple explanation of how to convert a Firestore date/Timestamp to a Javascript Date() and **why** you need to.

**Why convert?**

Firestore stores Dates as a [Timestamp object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp). *This is not the same as a Javascript Date() object.*

This was confusing to me because if you send a Date() object to Firestore, and then retrieve it, it will hand you back a Timestamp object. Like if you hand Firestore a dollar, it will hand you back 4 quarters. It is the same amount of money (or same date), but if you were expecting paper, and got metal, you would be confused.

**How to convert**

Luckily the Timestamp object has functions built into do give you a Javascript Date object: `toDate`

Note: Remember, `toDate` looks like the Javascript `toLocaleDateString()` or `toDateString()` but it is not. A JS Date() object and Firestore Timestamp object are not the same so don't make my rookie mistake of trying to use functions from one, on the other.

To convert a Firestore Timestamp into a Javascript date, just call `.toDate()` on the Timestamp.

```
//get the document from Firestore
let fireStoreTimestamp = doc.data().nameOfYourDateField;
let javascriptDate = fireStoreTimestamp.toDate();
```

Answer (score 4):

To help those still looking around for an answer to convert Firestore Date to JS Date to display in the web app. Here goes an example using typescript...

```
import {
  Timestamp,
} from "firebase/firestore";

interface IStuff {
  createdAt: Timestamp;
}

const insertStuff = async (text: string) => {
    await addDoc(collection(db, "coolstuff"), {
      text,
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
    });
};

<p>{item.createdAt?.toDate().toDateString()}</p>

// OR

<p>{item.createdAt?.toDate().toLocaleTimeString()}</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Extending Waleed Tariq answer, to get a more readable string:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    const formatDate = new Date(
        date.seconds * 1000 + date.nanoseconds / 1000000
    );
    return formatDate.toLocaleTimeString('en-us', { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
}

const timeStamp = {nanoseconds: 184000000, seconds: 1664826910};

console.log(formatDate(timeStamp))
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
new Date(firebaseDate.toDate())
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
let val = firebase.timestamp // as received from the database, the timestamp always comes in an object similar to this - {_nanoseconds: 488484, _seconds: 1635367}
    (new Date( (val.time._seconds + val.time._nanoseconds * 10 ** -9) * 1000)).toString().substring(17, 21)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/unix-timestamp) library to convert firebase firestore timestamp seconds to your local time.

```
newDate =  dayjs.unix(date.seconds).$d;
```

It will take

```
date: { 
    seconds: 1639506600, 
    nanoseconds: 0 
}
```

and convert it to

```
Date Sat Nov 16 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

to store timestamp into firestore:

```
import * as firebaseAdmin from "firebase-admin";

const created = firebaseAdmin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

// type
created: FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp | FirebaseFirestore.FieldValue | undefined;
```

To read back as a `js` `Date` object

```
const createDate = (created as FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp).toDate();
```

To read back as `RFC3339` string

```
const createDate = (created as FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp).toDate().toISOString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by far the most elegant, precise and easiest way to convert a firebase-timestamp to a date (no dependenceis etc. needed)

```
const date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
    'de-De', { 
           year: 'numeric', 
           month: 'numeric', 
           day: 'numeric', 
           hour: 'numeric', 
           minute: 'numeric' 
    }
).format(firebaseTimeStamp.toDate())
```

Here is a [cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/wip/intl-datetime) with all necesarry parameters

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And i figured out like this:

```
const createdAt = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());

// then using dayjs library you can display your date as you want.

const formatDate = dayjs.unix(createdAt.seconds).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Output should look like e.g. `2020-08-04`

Answer (score 0):

If you want don't want to lose the milliseconds you can do the following:

```
var myDate = a.record.dateCreated;
new Date((myDate.seconds + myDate.nanoseconds * 10 ** -9) * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

i work in angular.

i have an interface and a field date: Date.

the angular pipe date no work: order.date | date:'medium'

i change type of field date in interface

```
date: firebase.firestore.Timestamp
```

the angular pipe date work, but with function toDate()

`order.date.toDate() | date:'medium'`

Comment: Can you improve you question please?

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple really. Use this simple epoch converter function which converts epoch seconds into Javascript date and time.

```
  function getUNIXTime(dt) {
    let unix = new Date(dt * 1000);
    return unix.toUTCString().slice(5, 16);   
}
```

Pass the `timestamp.seconds` into this function then slice it according to your needs to get a string of text with date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Normally using any type (i.e. loginDate:any) and toDate() worked without problem in my all projects. But in my last project it didn't. I saw **seconds** in Timestamp object is **_seconds** anymore (Firebase 8.6.8). This type of change may have affected it. I don't know but i had no time so i used an alternative solution. A custom pipe. It can be used as an alternative:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'timestamp'
})
export class TimestampPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, format?: string) {

    if (!value) { return ''; }
    if (!format) { format = 'dd MMM  yy'; }

    return formatDate(value._seconds * 1000, format, 'tr');
  }
}
```

and

```
{{ item.endDate | timestamp}}
```

P.S. Type is not important with this pipe. Worked with loginDate:any or loginDate:Date well.

Answer (score 0):

**Web Firestore Timestamp:**

```
function dateToFirestoreTimestamp(dateString = ''){
        var timestampDate = new Date();     // this will return current date-time
        if(dateString != ''){
            // this will return timestamp according to provided date-time
            dateString = dateString.replace(' ', 'T');
            timestampDate = new Date(dateString);
        } 
        timestampDate = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(timestampDate);
        return timestampDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the **different** thing between **firestore timestamp** and **Javascript Date() object**. if you want to use javascript Date() object from firestore timestamp, this is what I do:

```
const foo = new Date(firestoreTimestamp.toDate());
```

then you can use the javascript Date() object, as usual. here are some references:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

For example, we want to retrieve the date from the Date() object with string format:

```
const foo = new Date(firestoreTimestamp.toDate());
foo.toLocaleDateString();
```

etc.