# I am trying to get readable date from firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get readable date from Timestamp data type in my firestore database.

```
for (var ticketDoc of ticketsSnapshot.docs) {
            var timeStamp = await ticketDoc.data().TimePreferred;
            console.log(timeStamp.toDate());
            var time = new Date(timeStamp).toDate();
            ticketDoc.data().TimePreferred = time;
            tickets.push(ticketDoc.data());
        }
```

I read the question about a similar problem at :

[How do I convert a Firestore date/Timestamp to a JS Date()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247445/how-do-i-convert-a-firestore-date-timestamp-to-a-js-date/55608383#55608383)

so, i tried to do same and i expect the output of readable date, although it gives me the correct result in

```
console.log(timeStamp.toDate());
```

but also it gives me an error. Console output as follow :-

```
2019-04-10T06:30:00.000Z
TypeError: (intermediate value).toDate is not a function
```

Not : I am trying to get readable date in postman

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm stuck with a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61166977/rendering-a-firestore-timestamp-in-react

Comment: In some cases you have to create the Timestamp object before being able to convert it:
`new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(timestamp._seconds, timestamp._nanoseconds)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
var time = new Date(timeStamp).toDate();
```

into this:

```
var time = new Date(timeStamp).toDateString();
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString):

> A string representing the date portion of the given Date object in human readable form in American English.

Comment: Now i am not getting the old error but the value still `1554877800` for seconds and `0` for nanoseconds

Comment: what is your timestamp variable equal to?

Comment: Try the following:  `var time = timeStamp.toDate();`

Comment: you are not storing a timestamp

Comment: In firestore data base it's type is timestamp, i entered it manually

Comment: `toDate()` is a method in class `Timestamp` thats why you get the error is not function https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.TimeStamp#todate

Comment: do this, for example `.collection("dates")
 .add({created: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()) })` this will store a timestamp in the database, then retrieve it `var timeStamp = await ticketDoc.data().created.;` `var time = timeStamp.toDate();`

Comment: In firestore data base it's type is timestamp. they are two, i can read just one in console not in postman

Comment: Okay, i got that the problem is in database.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why this timestamp object doesn't have the .toDate() extension, but if it has the 'seconds' and 'nanoseconds' properties, you can turn it to a JS Data with

```
Date(data.seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try in the following way

```
{{ formatDate(new Date(data.seconds*1000)) }}
```

You can use the format date function to display in desired format.

```
import moment from "moment";

  format_date(value) {
    if (value) {
      return moment(String(value)).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

For reasons that I don't know, it doesn't work at times, so a safer option would be to use the `seconds` and `nanoseconds` attributes found in the timestamp to convert it to date as follows:

```js
const date = new Date(timestamp.seconds*1000 + timestamp.nanoseconds/100000) 
// construct the date from the absolute time in milliseconds
```

Note:

- 1 second = 1000 ms
- 1 nanosecond = 10^-6 ms

Comment: In my case the attributes were named "_seconds" and "_nanoseconds".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing this to

```
var time = (new Date(timeStamp)).toDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `TimePreferred` field in your document is a `Timestamp`, you can get a valid `Date` object from it by simply calling `toDate()` on it.

So:

```
for (var ticketDoc of ticketsSnapshot.docs) {
    var date = ticketDoc.data().TimePreferred.toDate();
}
```

None of these calls are asynchronous or returning a promise, so you don't need `await`.

Comment: Hey Frank, that works when you fetch the timestamp but when you're creating it and want to immediately display the value with .toDate() on the app it generates the `.toDate is not a function` multiple times until the data is ready

Answer (score 0):

You have to first make sure that the timestamp object is truly of type Timestamp.
to do this, after you get the Timestamp from Firebase, create the Timestamp object:

```
const timestampObject: Timestamp = !!timeStamp
      ? new Timestamp(timeStamp.seconds, timeStamp.nanoseconds)
      : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Angular**

```
import { Location, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(
    public datepipe: DatePipe
  ) { }

const dayAsTimestamp = your_Timestamp_value;
const dayAsDate = new Date(dayAsTimestamp.seconds * 1000);
const dayAsString = this.datepipe.transform(dayAsDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

the possible reason toDate is not a function is you store the data in browser local storage which serialize object to JSON

since function cannot be serialized, so you are left with seconds and nanoseconds properties only