# How to convert firebase server date time to relative time(X minutes ago) in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs

I am taking the firebase server time and I want to convert that time to relative time(X seconds ago)

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

I tried to convert the date time using momentjs but got "invalid date"

```
moment(date).fromNow()
```

I am taking the date from firebase because I want the exact real date time (not the device date time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247445/how-do-i-convert-a-firestore-date-timestamp-to-a-js-date/52247484).

Write date using `serverTimestamp()` on Firestore.
Read date using [`createdAt.toDate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) to receive a Javascript Date object.
Moment date using with `moment(createdAt.toDate())`.
Moment relative : `moment(createdAt.toDate()).fromNow()`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a firebase server date to milliseconds using [fromMillis](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#static-frommillis) function
and then compare(subtract) it with the current date-time stamp(in milliseconds). Then divide the resultant milliseconds with 60000(1min) to show time lapsed in mins and with 60*60000 to show time lapsed in hours and similarly for days.