# Why are chat messages from firestore showing up in "groups"?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-gifted-chat

I am trying to use react-native-gifted-chat to build a chat room in my app.

Unfortunately, the chat's are appearing in "groups", not sequentially. For example,

1. I send a message
2. Someone else sends a message
3. I send another message
4. The messages I send group together, sometimes appearing above other messages, sometimes below

Here is an image of the issue:

[image]

****Notice how some younger messages are above some older messages, and grouped by the user who sent it!****

This is how I write the message to the DB:

```
onSend = async(message) => {
        this.setState({isTyping: true})
        await Firebase.firestore().collection("chat")
        .add({
            user: {
                _id: this.state.currentUser.id,
                name: this.state.currentUser.name,
                avatar: this.state.currentUser.avatar,
            },
            
        })
        .then(ref => this.setState({messageID: ref.id}))

        await Firebase.firestore().collection("chat")
        .doc(this.state.messageID)
        .set({
            _id: this.state.messageID,
            text: message[0].text,
            createdAt: dayjs(Moment(message[0].createdAt).format('LLL')).locale('en-ca').format()
        }, { merge: true })

    }

    render() { 
        return (
            <View style={{backgroundColor: '#000000', flex: 1}}>
                <GiftedChat
                    showUserAvatar={true}
                    isTyping={this.state.isTyping}
                    renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
                    messages={this.state.messages}
                    onSend={message => this.onSend(message)}
                    scrollToBottom
                    locale = { dayjs.locale('en-ca') }
                    showAvatarForEveryMessage = {true}
                    dateFormat = 'll'
                    timeFormat = 'LT'
                    onPressAvatar={user => this.getProfile(user)}
                />
            </View>
            
        )
        
    }
}
```

How I read the messages:

```
getCurrentMessages = async() => {

        await Firebase.firestore().collection("chat")
        .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
        .limit(50)
        .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
            const messages = []

            querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
                const { 
                    _id,
                    user,
                    text,
                    createdAt,
                    } = res.data();
    
                    messages.push({
                        key: res._id,
                        _id,
                        user,
                        text,
                        createdAt,
                    });
            })

            this.setState({
                messages,
                isLoading: false, 
                isTyping: false
            });
        })
    }
```

In firestore, this is how the time is written to the db:

[image]

Any idea why the messages are getting grouped together?

It seems like a simple case of pulling the messages from firestore ordered by date created, but that doesn't look like its working correctly.

I also get the following error when I send a message in gifted chat, could this have something to do with it?

```
react-native-gifted-chat] GiftedChat: `user` is missing for message {"_id":"lxYBMTV0sD7kaLQOsQLp","text":"Test 5","createdAt":"2021-01-25T22:05:00-08:00"}
```

[Some of the messages were sent from the east coast, some from the west coast of the USA. I wonder if this has something to do with the groupings?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the image it seems, the `createdAt` field is not a timestamp field, it's a `String`.

To add a timestamp field as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

```
createdAt: new Date();

or specific date-time

createdAt: firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());

or else for server time

createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

[image]

If you are able to get the field corrected, your `orderBy` query would retrieve the data in correct order.

Now the ordering happens on a `String` field, so it won't work as expected!

Comment: Yes, but this displays the time as "invalid date", and still even with a real timestamp, it orders things incorrectly! perhaps I can do this conversion to a timestamp AFTER I read from firestore?

Comment: if you do the conversion after read you have to order it manually; bcz the retrieved data ordered by a string field, in simple words, it's in incorrect order; So, it's good to save the data as timestamp!

Comment: Agreed, I am saving as a timestamp now, and trying to convert the date to the string format after reading

Comment: Trying to convert the timestamp in my firebase read (code above) but its not working. Any idea how to convert it within the for each while reading?

Comment: Cool! So, save the field as `timeStamp` -> query with `orderby` -> do the conversion if needed on any field while processing

Comment: for converting timestamp to `String` or `Date` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247445/how-do-i-convert-a-firestore-date-timestamp-to-a-js-date/52247484

Comment: Yes, exactly, but when I try to do messages.push({
                        key: res._id,
                        _id,
                        user,
                        text,
                        Moment(createdAt).format('LLL')
                    }); I get an error

Comment: Fixed it! messages.forEach((message) => {
                message.createdAt = Moment(message.createdAt.toDate()).format('LLL')
            })

Comment: Nevermind, still doesn't work. The messages are all out of order now again

Comment: do you still have old data that has `createdAt` as `String`?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, I think everything is fixed now. I have tried chatting between expo on my phone and simulator and everything is working fine now, no invalid date, no grouping messages. Will push this out as an update and hopefully it works globally