# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array

Tags: firebase, react-native

I worked now 33 days straight to code my app. Everything works fine. Yersterday evening there occurs this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I undo my changes, the error is still there. I decided to checkout an old commit. At the moment of commit, the codebase works. I have a running app in testmode on google play.

But today... even this code has this error. I could imagine this is a Firebase rules problem because they forced me after 30 days to change them. but after my changes the code runs for a while.

```
    [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.]
at http://192.168.178.47:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:281758:22 in <unknown>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase converts date/time to timestamp objects `{seconds: number, nanoseconds: number}` so if you passing that in the date field from your response object, you get that error. you have to convert the firebase date to javascript date or string.
[See this question from more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247445/how-do-i-convert-a-firestore-date-timestamp-to-a-js-date)

Comment: Oh thanks. I did not found this question. I give it a try. Thanks buddy.