# Is there a way to configure the Firestore timestamp outputs?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore to keep timestamps such as this log output:

```js
{
  my_timestamp: Timestamp { seconds: 1676783325, nanoseconds: 209000000 },
  product_name: 'Android'
}
```

I'm reading the values in my web app like this:

```js
...
  const result = []
  productDocs.forEach((productDoc: DocumentData) => {
    result.push({ id: productDoc.id, ...productDoc.data() })
  })

  return result
...
```

But I get an error:

```
Server Error
Error: Error serializing `.productDoc[0].my_timestamp` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/[pid]".
Reason: `object` ("[object Object]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
```

It seems to me that the Timestamp object is not easily accepted as part of the object.  My solution is to iterate through each `Object.entries(productDoc).forEach(productData)...` and reformat the Timestamp object and then push on an array.

This seems like a manual way to go about this so I'd like to make sure I'm parsing the timestamp object properly and I'm not missing some way where I can just read the whole result from Firebase as an object with doing nothing to the timestamp.

It seems [How do I convert a Firestore date/Timestamp to a JS Date()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247445/how-do-i-convert-a-firestore-date-timestamp-to-a-js-date) is the only way where I have to take the object apart and convert the values.

I didn't see a way to do this on https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp other than just converting the Firebase object.