# how to change a timestamp date from firebase to a javascript date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a calendar with react, redux, react big calendar and firebase. the problem is that the events are not displayed in the calendar. I think that this is because the format of the dates, is in seconds and nanoseconds.

Searching how to solve this i found that using `toDate()` and `new Date()` can convert the dates to javascript dates, but it didn't work.

and already read: [How do I convert a Firestore date/Timestamp to a JS Date()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247445/how-do-i-convert-a-firestore-date-timestamp-to-a-js-date)

but still cant figure out how to do it

i tried doing this buti get "invalid date":

```
events.map(event => console.log(toDate(event.start)))
```

i hope that someone can help me. thanks!!

github: https://github.com/guidomora/peluqueria-new-calendar.git

Code to return the events from firebase:

```
  const startLoadingEvents = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "tobias"));
    const events = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      events.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()});
    });
    dispatch(setEvent(events))
  };
```

Console:

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Car.png)

Event in firebase:

[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmVt2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer on the other question you cited is saying that there is a toDate **method** on a Timestamp object.  What you tried:

```
toDate(event.start))
```

is not calling a method.  That's just calling a standalone function called "toDate", and there is no such function provided by the Firestore SDK.

If you are saying that `event.start` is a Firestore Timestamp type object, then you can call its `toDate` method like this:

```
event.start.toDate()
```

to get a Date out of it.  But we can't see what `event.start` is exactly, so I'm just guessing here.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!! it was that   event.start.toDate()